Requests permission even though it has - SAFARI web
I am implementing a voice recording functionality which records when the user requests it. Below is the code
navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then((stream) => {
                console.log("streaming started....");
             )};

For testing purposes, I have given the site to permanently allow.
However when I run this code it asks for the permissions again.
Is this a default behaviour in Safari or is there something wrong with the code?

